# Being put on the property deeds of jointly owned house

Tags: united-kingdom, capital-gains-tax, jointly-held-property, title

This is my conundrum. I bought a house 17 years ago with my brother.

The problem we have is that I am not on the deeds. We bought the house as an investment property.

I was not considered for the mortgage as I had just started as a contractor through my own company. This was also advice given by the conveyancing solicitor i.e. it's not necessary for you to go onto the deeds. Bad advice I feel.

So, only my brother's name was put onto the mortgage and, as such, onto the deeds.

I moved into the house when my marriage broke down in 2003 and have been here ever since.
Obviously, this is my primary residence and has been for nearly 16 years, as such I do 
not wish to incur any additional costs i.e. CG when we come to sell the house.

We have just been in touch with the mortgage provider. They will not consider me to go onto the mortgage as I am living here and it is a BTL mortgage.

The only way forward, that I can see, is to pay off the mortgage and then put me onto the title using an AP1 and a TR1. Can anyone see a simpler solution, i.e. drawing up a retrospective agreement or can you see any problems that may arise with this approach?

I was also thinking of a Declaration of Beneficial Interest?

Any input would be gratefully received.

Thanks very much.

Comment: I don't know the UK mortgage scene at all, but have you approached a different bank about issuing you a mortgage? It seems like any other sale except the seller happens to be your brother and you happen to be currently 'renting' the place you intend to buy.

Comment: Hi.  I own the property already.  I bought the property with my brother 17 years ago.  I just need to be put onto the title deeds, as such I need to put onto the existing mortgage, so that I can then be put onto the deeds.  The current mortgage provider will not do this as I am living here.  Either we have to clear the mortgage and then I can be put on without their authority or I need to find another way to show that I actually own the property and have done for 17 years.  I have a paper trail a mile wide but for tax purposes, I should imagine that this will not be enough.  Thanks.

Comment: I was thinking that in the eyes of banks/gov you don't actually own it since you're not on the deed/mortgage, so that would enable you to 'buy' it from your brother.

Comment: Ah.  I'm with you now.  Unfortunately,  I have MS and I have been out of work for several years now, so unfortunately I don't have the capital and I wouldn't be considered for a mortgage.  Nice thought though.  If I had been in work, I would probably have done that.

Comment: I think you probably need to speak to an accountant or solicitor who deals with property. My (non-expert) suspicion is that you do not own the property at all, and you have been living there as your brother's tenant all this time. If you've been helping to pay the mortgage, then that might help...or it might make no difference. It's possible that your brother could just give you a nominal share in the property for a nominal fee (tenants-in-common with non-equal shares), though note that there could be tax payable. That would normally be enough to at least start discussions with a lender.

Comment: A note on mortgage types: based on what you've said, there would be two reasons for the lender rejecting adding you to _this_ mortgage: (1) "normal" (i.e. unregulated) BTL mortgages normally prohibit having a family member as a tenant; and (2) BTL mortgages normally prohibit the owner from living in his property. So whether you're a tenant or the owner, you may be breaching the terms of the current mortgage. Once you are established as the joint owner, you may then be able to apply for a _residential_ mortgage.

Comment: Hi,  I've worked it out.  You use a bare Declaration of Trust i.e. I, David,  declare hat I hold the property,  xxxx, in equal share with xxxx and have done since it's purchase on the xxxx.  Etc.  This can be retrospective, with proof which I have ample of i.e. I paid half the deposit,  I paid half the renovation costs,  I paid off half the mortgage 14 years ago and have many emails.  I don't have to inform the mortgage provider  or anyone else.  Very simple.  Very bad advice by the original conveyancing solicitor to put us in this position.

Comment: Oh btw Steve, I most definitely own the house and I really resent the implication but I thank you for your advice anyway.